# Getting appsettings.json settings into an object of class type in .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, appsettings

I wanted to pull the configuration from `appsettings.json` into an object of type `ExchangeOptions`. I know that `configuration.Get<T>()` works in ASP.NET Core, but I forgot the correct package for .NET Core Console application. I currently have the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

The example below is pretty self explanatory.

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  "ExchangeConfiguration": {
    "Exchange": "Binance",
    "ApiKey": "modify",
    "SecretKey": "modify"
  }
}
```

#### Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

public class ExchangeOptions
{
    public Exchange Exchange { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    
        // These work fine
        var exchange = configuration["ExchangeConfiguration:Exchange"];
        var apiKey = configuration["ExchangeConfiguration:ApiKey"];
        var secretKey = configuration["ExchangeConfiguration:SecretKey"];

        // This doesn't work, because I don't have the right NuGet package
        ExchangeOptions exchangeOptions = configuration.Get<ExchangeOptions>();
    
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct package for `configuration.Get<ExchangeOptions>()` was `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`. Thanks anyway!